# Android context in non-actitvity class

Tags: android, android-activity, toast, android-context

I'm using [**Android Priority Job Queue**](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) And if an error occurs inside the Job, a Toast should be shown. I can not Handover the context as a parameter since it's not serializable. is it even possible to get a context and show a toast?

Comment: `Toast` is *not* a good choice for an error condition, as the user can easily miss it. I would recommend that you use an event bus, as noted in the docs, to notify your UI about error conditions. The activity or fragment that responds to the event can then do something appropriate to notify the user.

Comment: I've never used that library before but I see that the Job is added from within an Activity .. Does `getActivity()` not work here ?

Comment: no sadly it doesn't I will try @CommonsWare idea and implement an EventBus

Comment: It can be done, but you have to run it as a separate task.